# multiple layout with angularjs in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-routing

I have two layout first for visitor second for management

Rout:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ( $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', { templateUrl: 'Home/Main', })
                .when('/Manage', { templateUrl: 'Manage/Index', caseInsensitiveMatch: true })
                .when('/Manage/Item/:itemId?', { templateUrl: '/Item/Index/',caseInsensitiveMatch: true});
        }
      ]);
```

First ng-view  in home/index and second ng-view in manage/index
but /Item not loaded in manage ng-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `area` in your mvc project for your manage layout
then create your own route provider for manage layout

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ( $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', { templateUrl: 'Manage/Home/Main', })
                .when('/Manage', { templateUrl: 'Manage/Manage/Index', caseInsensitiveMatch: true })
                .when('/Manage/Item/:itemId?', { templateUrl: 'Manage/Item/Index/',caseInsensitiveMatch: true});
        }
      ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

IMO areas in MVC pretty much suck.  I hate the idea of duplicating most of your MVC app just to render a different layout.

In my situation, I have a layout for when the user hasn't been authenticated and another layout for when they have.  In my case, I have an AngularJS SPA on top of an MVC app.  Since it's a SPA, I have a single View with a `<div ng-view></div>` element.  The solution I implemented utilizes the _ViewStart.chtml file:

```
@{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UnauthorizedLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

I'm using a conditional with the exposed IPrincipal object, but you could put whatever conditional logic you want in there.